# In a bash script how to loop through files sorted by date

Tags: bash, sorting

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='host'
USER='user@example.com'
PASSWD='pwd'

for FILE in *.avi
do
    ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
    quote USER $USER
    quote PASS $PASSWD
    binary
    put $FILE
    rm FILE 
    quit
done
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

How do I ensure that I process the oldest file first?  I have seen a lot of hacks that use ls -t, but there has to be a simpler way.

Comment: Well, [globbing is always alphabetical](https://serverfault.com/a/122743)... Are you looking for an alternative to `ls` because its output is supposedly only meant for human consumption?

Comment: There isn't a simpler way, at least not in `bash`. Use a shell like `zsh` which provides a way to process glob expansions. For example, the glob qualifer `(om)` in `for FILE in *.avi(om); do` ensures the files are iterated over in increasing order of their modification times.

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of files into an array or list and then sort them by date?

Comment: @Chiwda: As chepner said, use zsh. Or use Perl or Ruby or anything else. If you really do it in bash, you have to roll out the sorting algorithm by hand. You could first collect the list of files, then calculate for each file the modification time (using `stat`, with format %Y, i.e. number of seconds from epoch).  Create a text file, where each line contains two fields: The time stamp, and the file name. Use  `sort` to sort this file on the first field in numeric order. Then, the sorted file will have in the second field of each line the files sorted by age.

Comment: This might help: `xmlstarlet ls`

Comment: @user1934428 Your solution with a file with filenames will fail for filenames with a newline. Making a sorting algorith with `stat` is a good idea.

Comment: @WalterA : You are right. So, instead of the filename, we should place into the file-to-be-sorted an index to the bash array which holds the unsorted list of files. Or, shoot people who create files with embedded newlines. The former way is technically, the latter one emotionally sound.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would modify your `for` loop with this:

```
for FILE in `ls -tU *.avi`
do
  #
  # loop content here with ${FILE}
  #
done
```

From the `ls` docs:

```
-t      Sort by time modified (most recently modified first) before 
        sorting the operands by lexicographical order.
-U      Use time of file creation, instead of last modification for 
        sorting (-t) or long output (-l).
```

Comment: The `-U` option is implementation dependent, and means different things in BSD and GNU `ls`. Also, this breaks for filenames which can be altered by word splitting or pathname expansion.

Comment: Violating PItfall No. 1 will always get your dinged.... ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) -- There is a reason they call it **Pitfall No. 1**.

Comment: If the environment were controlled - in other words, I was creating the files, so I could control for spaces or newlines (OMG!) in filenames, then this solution would work, right?

Comment: While you've probably already figured it out, to satisfy your requirement of sorting by oldest file first, use -tr (sorts by time in reverse order).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - it's great to say avoid a pitfall, but then you should offer another solution. What other solution do you recommend?

Comment: @PhillipBoushy - the link provided in the comment provides an in-depth discussion of the topic with the proper alternatives.

Comment: Yes, it covers that you shouldn’t and other ways to iterate through a list of files but not how to iterate a list of files *ordered by date* and that’s core to this question. Do you have any recommendations for that?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments of another answer, it's generally a bad practice to rely on the output of `ls` in scripts.  While this is not simpler, I'd suggest something more like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

SOME_DIR=/some/directory/

for f in $(find "${SOME_DIR}" -type f -name "*" -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort | awk '{print $2}'); do
    echo "${f}"
done
```

Breaking this down a bit, it first uses `find` to get a list which includes file name (`%p`) prefixed with the file's last modification timestamp (`%T`) in a basic date and time format (`+`), with the values separated by a tab (`\t`) and each pair of values terminated by a new line (`\n`).  The `sort` gives us pairs of values in oldest-to-newest order (use `sort -r` if you want the opposite).  Finally, `awk` removes the last modification timestamp leaving the file name and a newline.

Comment: filenames with whitespaces are broken