# AWS CLI syncing file from folder to S3 in FIFO method

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using `aws s3 sync` to send files from a local folder to S3, but it doesn't support FIFO method.

This means that if 5 files are generated, it should sync the first file which is got generated because I am using Lambda on S3 trigger to get file name in SQS.

My current syntax:

```
aws s3 sync filepath S3path --no-progress --storage-class STANDARD_IA
```

Any suggestion how to sync file in sequence?

Comment: The `aws s3 sync` command cannot send files in a specific order. It probably does it sorted based on the name of files. Can you clarify why you need to sync the files in creation order?

Comment: yes bcz i have lambda function which has trigger on s3 bucket and process the file for other operation ,which need to be in sequence, for example i can not have price file before the product file

Comment: In that case, you will need to find a different way to copy the files. Or, add some logic to the Lambda functions that can check for the presence of files and only perform work when all files are present.

Comment: check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233180/in-a-bash-script-how-to-loop-through-files-sorted-by-date it will allow you to process files individually in order of the timestamp. Then you'll be able to use just aws s3 cp, instead of sync.