# How to safely iterate glob with time modified order?

Tags: bash

Currently, I am doing this in a bash script.

```bash
for i in $(ls -tr *.tar); do
# something
done
```

When I run `shellcheck`, I got a (correct) warning

```
for i in $(ls -tr *.tar); do
         ^-------------^ SC2045 (warning): Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs.
```

OK, but what to do here? I cannot use globs, or at least I don't know how.

I will add I *need* to keep the order as `ls -tr` does, that is, ordered by time modified (and reversed, newest at the bottom).

I have seen some ways to do this, some of them on Stack Overflow (for example [In a bash script how to loop through files sorted by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233180/in-a-bash-script-how-to-loop-through-files-sorted-by-date) ), doing find/sort/awk combo, but that all seem even more fragile than just using `ls`.

Is there a *safe* way to do this? (I am using Linux with "standard" coreutils etc)

Comment: I have decided between serverfault, stackoverflow and linux SE. I _think_ it belongs here, as it is basically a language (bash) problem, but I am fine with moving.

Comment: This is covered by [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  PERFECT, please add that as an answer!

Comment: ...I have done so already; is there anything in the FAQ contents that you think I should add?

Comment: If you are willing to switch shells, `zsh` glob modifiers let you affect the order in which the resulting files are generated, including sorting them by time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  All the solutions in the Bash FAQ are objectively worse than the `$(ls -tr *.tar)` original.  `IFS`, `read`, `find`, ... and then the ball rolls down this spiral gutter, activating a lever, which releases some sand that eventually tips a scale which raises a match, causing it to strike, and then light a candle, which burns through a string ...

Comment: @chepner well... I _can_ shell out to `zsh` :) but in general I use way too many bashisms elsewhere

Comment: @Kaz, "objectively worse"? There are filenames that can exist that `ls` cannot unambiguously represent in a machine-readable way. That rules it out. Nothing that correctly handles every possible filename can be worse than something that doesn't. Sure, there are lots of moving parts -- unfortunately, that's necessary, _because the POSIX spec was written before people were seriously thinking about security_; you didn't have concerns back then about malicious filenames with literal newlines, and what happens if someone runs `mkdir -p /uploads/$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/deleteme`.

Comment: ...the focus was instead on trying to rationalize the places where AT&T and BSD forks of UNIX had made different decisions and come up with a single spec that both of them could follow; POSIX _did that_, but it left a lot of behaviors up in the air. Writing robust shell scripts, then, means sometimes going to some extra lengths (and literally, sometimes, some extra code length) to lock down behavior in the corner cases where the spec wasn't thought through.

Comment: @Kaz, ...I agree that that makes POSIX-family shell a bad language! It's much better to write code in Go or Rust instead -- but if you _are_ going to write in a shell language, then it behooves you to learn the pitfalls and how to work around them, instead of pointing and laughing at the people who are doing the necessary work to make their code robust despite building on a rotten foundation.

Comment: @Kaz, ...btw, I've been there in real life for a major data loss incident caused by someone _not_ being careful in their backup scripts -- code handling files that "couldn't possibly" have any name that didn't fit a specific format; then a new (still in-house!) client was added writing to the directory -- written in Python, but it used a C library that had a bug and wrote random data into a position behind a bad pointer, which happened to at one point be pointing into a string later used for a filename. We lost TBs of billing records because someone was sloppy with their shell practices.

Comment: @Kaz, ...part of the point of telling that story: You _don't always know_ ahead-of-time when doing the extra work to get the corner cases right is going to matter; getting in the habit of _always_ doing the safe thing (and, on code review, _always_ flagging it when someone isn't!) means you don't get caught out when it really _does_ matter by surprise.

Comment: (to be fair, I'll grant that "how many characters of code is this?" is an objective measure; but "does this perform the desired operation in presence of all possible input data?" is _also_ an objective measure; which of those is more _important_ depends on priorities, which are arguably inherently _subjective_, but I personally am going to have a hard trouble respecting the priorities of anyone who's building production systems by playing code golf).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Simplifying the code by eliminating requirements from the problem isn't code golf. It's "requirements golf", and that's an excellent thing to play in production. At least, to play well, at the pro level.  How many auxiliary/spurious requirements, which are not specific to this problem but are dragged in due to the solution environment/tooling, can we drop in this situation, with proper justification?

Comment: @Kaz, note the word "safely" in the title. I interpret "safety" in this context to mean "correctly" -- having unambiguous input that allows the code reading it to know the filenames of all matches in datetime order. If it doesn't handle all filenames correctly, it's failing to meet that basic requirement; you're no longer returning "the filenames of all matches" unless there are extraneous restrictions applied to that set of names. `ls` _can't do that_ for all the reasons given in [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)...

Comment: @Kaz, ...and if you're trying to soften the requirement "return the filenames" to "return the subset of _trivial_ filenames in correct order, possibly with extra garbage mixed in anywhere a nontrivial filename was encountered", that's making extra work (new requirements!) on _other_ parts of the system, which then in order to be correct need to validate that the names they receive are valid and that they don't behave in undesired ways in presence of unwanted data.

Comment: @Kaz, ...but -- I'm coming at this from the perspective of someone who's been working with bash for a long time and knows where the bodies are hidden. I know you need to clear `IFS` before using `read` so it doesn't ignore leading or trailing whitespace; I know you need the `-r` argument to `read` so it doesn't try to treat backslash literals as syntax rather than literal data; etc etc -- _when knowing where the pitfalls are_, an idiom that otherwise might look hairy breaks down into a bunch of components each of which has a sound justification and is there for good reason.

Comment: @Kaz, ...even if that "good reason" in many cases is working around horribly problematic default behaviors that are the consequence of decisions people made in the 1970s without knowing what the consequences would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Largely, this is covered by [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003); the below extracts a relevant subset.

---

On a GNU system, `find`'s `-printf` can print timestamp metadata.

Using NUL-delimited output and `sort -z` ensures correct operation with all possible filenames, including ones with literal newlines included (the NUL is the only character that cannot possibly exist in a path across all UNIXy systems).

```
while IFS= read -r -d : time && IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  echo "Read ${file} with timestamp ${time}"
done < <(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@:%p\0' | sort -zn)
```

The use of `-printf` ensures a well-defined output format, and is thus (assuming, again, availability of GNU tools) not at all fragile.

If you want to reverse the order and list newest-to-oldest, add the `-r` argument to `sort`.

Comment: Using `-d ' '` and then `-d ''` looks like a source of future bugs. Maybe `-printf '%T@\0%p\0'`?

Comment: @glennjackman, hm. Maybe something separate like a `:`; I do prefer to keep it two separate delimiters so if we somehow get out of sync there's room to recover, but you're right that that's a subtle difference.

Comment: Why is that? Is there a problem reading a "line" with a timestamp and then a "line" with a filename? What's a scenario that gets us "out of sync"?

Comment: @glennjackman, "Why is that?" -- ...unambiguous wire file formats are better than ambiguous ones? If it's two different delimiters, you _know_ when you see a NUL that we've finished not just a field but a record. As for "what gets us out of sync"... _shrug_, maybe someone who's doing some debugging attaches sysdig or strace to a running process and only starts reading the stream partway through.

Comment: @glennjackman, I'll happily grant that this is more a matter of personal design sensibilities than anything else; if you want to paint your bikeshed a different color, by all means do.

Comment: Good correction

Answer (score -1):

Correct way:

```
for i in *.tar
do
[[ -e "$i" ]] || break  # handle the case of no *.tar files
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: But that doesn't sort by time modified, which `ls -tr` does! I need that.

Comment: I have clarified that I need to keep the property of `ls -tr`